# C++ : 2D array by reference? Why does this function work

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array, 2d

What does the parameter printArray(int (&a)[n][m]) mean? Why are the parentheses necessary and why does only 1 value need to be provided to the printArray function? how does the function know n and m when called?

```
template <size_t n, size_t m>
void printArray(int (&a)[n][m]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Example I:" << endl;
    int ab[2][5];
    printArray(ab);
    cout << "Example II:" << endl;
    int b[2][5] = {{1, 2, 3}};
    printArray(b);
    cout << "Example III:"<< endl;
    int c[][5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    printArray(c);
    cout << "Example IV:" << endl;
    int d[][5] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7}};
    printArray(d);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the parameter `printArray(int (&a)[n][m])` mean?

It means that `a` is a reference to an object of type `int[n][m]`. `int[n][m]` is an array of `m` objects of type `int[n]`. `int[n]` is an array of `n` objects of type `int`. So, `a` is a reference to a 2d array with dimensions `n` and `m`.

`n` and `m` are template arguments that were declared in `template <size_t n, size_t m>`. The type of both argument is `size_t`, which is an integer type.

> Why are the parentheses necessary

Because the &-token binds to left. `int&` is a reference to int. `int& a[n]` would syntactically mean that `a` is an array of references (such arrays are not allowed though). The parentheses are used to disambiguate whether the &-token declares an (array of) reference to int, or a reference to an array.

> and why does only 1 value need to be provided to the printArray function?

There is exactly one argument to the function: `a`. If you pass a value that can be bound to an array reference of appropriate type, then it works. In all your examples the arguments are 2d arrays of integers, so they are correct.

> how does the function know n and m when called?

The compiler knows because size of an array is part of the type of the array. And because of template argument deduction. When a template argument is not specified explicitly, it may be deduced from the arguments of the function. In this case, if you pass an argument of type `int[2][5]`, then `n` is deduced to be 2 and `m` is deduced to be 5.

You could even add a template type argument and let that be deduced:

```
template <size_t n, size_t m, typename T>
void printArray(T (&a)[n][m])
```

`T` would be deduced to be `int`, if you were to pass a 2d array of integers.

> if an array of references isn't allowed, why can't the compiler deduce that the parenthesis is not necessary.

If `int &a[n]` would mean a reference to an array, because there can't be arrays of references, then it would confuse programmers that `int *a[n]` is not a pointer to an array, because there can be arrays of pointers.

Besides, this would complicate the language by adding a special case for references that is unnecessary.

> why isn't the form: printArray(int[n][m] &a)

More simply, why can't arrays be declared by `int[n] a` instead of `int a[n]`. Because the latter syntax was chosen by (presumably Dennis Ritchie when he was) designer of the C language.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thank you very much! A few questions, if an array of references isn't allowed, why can't the compiler deduce that the parenthesis is not necessary. Furthermore, why isn't the form: printArray(int[n][m] &a)  allowed

Comment: @JohnathanRice 1) because of the way the compiler works, it will just assume you mean right (since normally, this is what you would mean) and think you messed up and throw an error 2) Not sure I can answer properly, but I would imagine because it breaks syntax. [] operators generally go after the identifier (variable) name, not before. Not 100% sure, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply taking an array by reference. As far as usage of the passed array goes inside the function, you typically will write exactly the same code as you would have otherwise. The only difference is that it preserves its array type.

When you pass arrays "by value" to a function it's actually decayed into a pointer to its first element. Passing it by reference (or by address) prevents this decay in this usage.

In fact, even if you specify an extent for the first dimension in the parameter, the compiler will ignore it if the array is passed "by value".

This is a template programming trick to deduce the extent of the first dimension, which would otherwise by lost if you had written:

```
template<size_t m>
void printArray(int a[][m]) {...}
```

Thus the alternative would have been something less tidy like:

```
template<size_t m>
void printArray(int a[][m], size_t n) {...}
```

The parenthesis are required because `int &a[n][m]` is a 2D array of references, which is illegal because you cannot make an array of reference. The parenthesis in `int (&a)[n][m]` makes this "reference to nxm array of int".